# Scala HOF Syntax for a function that takes a generic argument T1 and returns a seq of generic result T2: Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Scala Play Framework and currently I have routes that handle requests with optional params `limit` and `skip`. Function definition is as shown below:

I have a route like this:

```
GET / controller.index(skip:Option[Int],limit:Option[Int])
```

And index does the following:

```
def index(skip:Option[Int],limit:Option[Int]): Action[AnyContent]
```

However I want to return a sequence of specific case classes like:

`case class User(id: String,name: String)`

Now I have a lot of routes like this where skip and limit are passed as optional query parameters, so Ideally I want to wrap all my other functions with a generic higher order function that looks like this:

```
case class Result[T] (
                     data: T,
                     skip: Option[Int],
                     limit: Option[Int]
                     )
object TestRunner extends App {
  def paginationHandler[T1,T2](f: T2 => Seq[T1], content: Result[T2]): Seq[T1] = {
    val result = f(content.data)
    val sliced = result slice(content.skip.getOrElse(0), content.skip.getOrElse(0) + content.limit.getOrElse(10))
    sliced
  }

  def getCategories(categories:Seq[String]): Seq[String] = categories

  val results = paginationHandler[String,Seq[String]](getCategories,Result[Seq[String]](Seq("Abc","Def","Ghi"),Some(0),Some(1)))
  println(results)
}
```

But I am struggling a lot with syntax. I need to understand how can I format the syntax of my `index` function so that it becomes a generic and returns `Seq[T]` where `T` is generic type instead of returning `AnyContent`.

Comment: To improve type inference it is usually better to put the data first and then the function in a different parameter group, like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/D9kSww7pSZmaFnB8Nemu0A

Comment: I see this is extremely helpful thanks Luis, additionally I would like to know how can one write syntax of the same middleware or a HOF that would intercept the request by checking skip or limit and if they exist then truncate the data accordingly

Comment: I have zero experience with **Play** so no idea, the best may be to open a new more focused question and add the `Play` tag.